# Error trying to use IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.3 diff tool as merge / diff tool for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellij-idea, ankhsvn

Using the IntelliJ instructions at http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/working-with-intellij-idea-features-from-command-line.html for running the IntelliJ IDEA diff tool from the command line, I have tried to configure Visual Studio 2010 + AnkhSVN with the following External Merge Tool command (Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Subversion User Tools):

```
"<IntelliJ IDEA Home>\bin\idea.exe" diff $(Theirs) $(Mine)
```

But when I go to edit a merge conflict (right click the file in Solution Explorer -> Edit Conflicts), idea.exe reports the following error:

> Error showing diff: Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of
>   com/intellij/openapi/fileEditor/impl/FileEditorProviderManagerImpl.getProviders
>   must not be null

Any ideas what is going wrong? Is this an IDEA bug? Or perhaps `$(Theirs)` and `$(Mine)` are not the macros I think they are (I expect them to expand out to the full file paths).

Comment: IDEA may be not aware of these file types yet, you need to open `Settings` | `File Types` and assign the extensions of the files you try to compare to some type.

Comment: @CrazyCoder - I think your hunch about the source of the error was correct, but I believe the real issue was that I was trying to use `diff` to edit merge conflicts (and so I'm guessing $(Theirs) and $(Mine) had  extensions like rXXX). Is it possible to use the IDEA merge tool from the command line? i.e. the tool described at  http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/resolving-conflicts.html

Comment: Merge works with 3 files, see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69292.